# PySNMP Error: pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am running a Python program on a Windows XP machine. When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp\smi\builder.pyt, line 230, in loadModules...
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: MIB file "SNMPv2-MIB.py[co]" not found in search path
```

The file SNMPv2-MIB.py is currently located in `C:\Python27\Lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs`. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth : The solution has been provided here so I guess we can mark the other question as duplicate as the other one is more recent.

Comment: @pyfunc. Already done, I hadn't noticed the other one was more recent. I can't undo my vote but I did vote to close that one as well. If anyone wants to vote on it, it's at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732439/errors-using-pysnmp-on-windows-xp

Answer (score 7):

if a mib is missing make sure you have performed a `pip install pysnmp-mibs` first if you used `pip install pysnmp`.

Comment: Six years later you would think this would be mentioned at http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/index.html, but it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same issue.  I filed a bug for it and included a patch:
https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3204704&group_id=14735&atid=114735

As Sivakumar says, the reason it's failing is because pysnmp is looking for MIBs with a .pyc or .pyw extension.  pysnmp gets these extensions from imp.get_suffixes().  Based on the way pysnmp deals with the extensions returned from this function, the .pyw entry will overwrite the .py entry.  The fix I proposed will simply ignore the .pyw extension.

If you install the library from the .egg it should work fine because the .egg includes compiled (pyc) MIBs.

Comment: This solved for me.. I was stripping the pyc's around to squeeze on size, but pysnmp didn't like it so restoring it with a simple `python -m compileall ./` diddathing.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to load the MIB file.

Can you check :

```
>>> print builder.MibBuilder().getMibPath()
```

Usually this should be ok as the mib instances should be in

```
pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances
```

Code where error is raised in builder.py

```
if not self.__modSeen.has_key(modName):
    raise error.SmiError(
        'MIB file \"%s\" not found in search path' % (modName and modName + ".py[co]")
            )
```

Usually this should get solved by calling setMibPath on the mibBuilder instance before calling loadModules.

Since the path you are getting

```
C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances, 
C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs, 
C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp_mibs
```

Why don't you move the file to one of these directories? 
The place where it is currently located

- C:\Python27\Lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs

is not among the paths that you got via builder.MibBuilder().getMibPath()

Comment: C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances, C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp\smi\mibs, C:\Python27\lib\pysnmp_mibs

Comment: why is it looking for "SNMPv2-MIB.py[co]" instead of SNMPv2-MIB.py?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue (with pysnmp-4.2.5). I generated my own MIB python file using:

```
build-pysnmp-mib -o IF-MIB.py /usr/share/mibs/ietf/IF-MIB
```

on RHEL6 (`build-pysnmp-mib` does not work on RHEL5 as it requires libsmi version > 0.4.5 and RHEL5 just has this version while RHEL6 has 0.4.8).

Then I copied the generated file IF-MIB.py into the directory where the other python MIB files of pysnmp are located, (`/.../site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/`)

Answer (score 0):

Today i too face this same issue. The mibs path is correctly set. While running the pysnmp in debugging mode, i am able to found that it is expecting a SNMPv2-MIB.pyc or .pyw file.

Since i have unzipped the pysnmp from source and using it, the corresponding pyc file for the mib module is not available in that folder structure. I havent tried compiling the corresponding .py files available in the pysnmp-4.1.13a\pysnmp\smi\mibs\instances or pysnmp-4.1.13a\pysnmp\smi\mibs, instead i used the easyinstall script to download the pysnmp module.

With the egg file, now the issue is not coming.

Thanks
Sivakumar