# How to load a custom MIB

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib, snmp-trap

I have been trying to create a trap listener using the PySNMP library, that should load a custom MIB file (already compiled for PySNMP to use with mibdump.py), and print the traps received in a readable format of field name = value.

However, the code is unable to find the MIB files and returns an error:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: MIB file "BMC-CONTROLMEM-MIB.py[co]" not found in search path (DirMibSource('/home/ign
asi/Workspace/trap-endpoint/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'), 
DirMibSource('/home/ignasi/Workspace/trap-endpoint/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs/instances'),
DirMibSource('/home/ignasi/Workspace/trap-endpo
int/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysnmp_mibs'),
DirMibSource('/home/ignasi/.pysnmp/mibs'), 
DirMibSource('python_packaged_mibs'), 
DirMibSource('/home/ignasi/.pysnmp/mibs'))
```

I started by following the examples ([this](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html)), however when I point to my MIB:

```
for (errorIndication,
        errorStatus,
        errorIndex,
        varBinds) in bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                            UsmUserData('usr-none-none'),
                            UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 5000)),
                            ContextData(),
                            0, 50,
                            ObjectType(
                                ObjectIdentity('BMC-CONTROLMEM-MIB', 'controlmAlert').addMibSource('/home/ignasi/.pysnmp/mibs').addMibSource('python_packaged_mibs')
                            ),
                            lexicographicMode=False):
```

It returns that error.

I have tried to list all paths as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730925/pysnmp-error-pysnmp-smi-error-smierror) and copy the MIB to all folders with no success.

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837417/pysnmp-smi-error-mibnotfounderror-no-module-snmp-framework-mib-loaded-at-pys) post and I do not understand how to generate the MIB in the /instances folder, with the "__" prefix.

Lastly, I do not understand why is searching for a .py[co] file, is it something that must be also compiled?

```
...modName and modName + "***.py[co]***", ', '.join([str(x) for x in self.__mibSources]))
pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError: MIB file "BMC-CONTROLMEM-MIB.***py[co]***"
```

Is there something I missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to compile MIBs explicitly - that would happen behind the scenes.

If you are building a trap listener (notification receiver), you will get hold of the variable-bindings it received. I am guessing that at this point you should walk over them and resolve against the MIB like [this](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/hlapi/varbinds.py#L90):

```
varBinds = [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(*varBind).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
            for varBind in varBinds]
```

Prior to resolving varBinds, you might need to [pre-load the MIBs](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.loadMibs) you intend to receive the OIDs for. Prior to that you are likely to want to [point pysnmp](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.addAsn1MibSource) to a location holding all these MIBs and their dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! now it loads and compiles the MIB correctly! without errors!